# Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#

I'm getting the above error. I saw other similar posts on this error but I don't seem to find where the problem is. I changed my class type to static and the error resists. This is the entire code to my main form class:

I Edited my class. This is how it looks like now and the error has changed to:Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'PhoneFind.frmMain'; another partial declaration of this type exists.

```
namespace PhoneFind
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        // the path to the temporary file to store the webresponse
        String path = "c:\\Temp\\webresponse.txt";
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboSelectSearchEngine.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ofdPhones.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            listbxMessages.Items.Clear();
            addItemToListBox(listbxMessages, "Welcome to ActionBase Phone Find!");
            addItemToListBox(listbxMessages, "Select the file containing the numbers.");
            radioNumbers.Checked = true;
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnLoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ofdPhones.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFile.Text = ofdPhones.FileName;

                // Read the file line by line and add the numbers to the numbers listbox.
                listbxNumbers.Items.Clear();
                String line;
                int numbersCounter = 0;
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofdPhones.FileName);
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    listbxNumbers.Items.Add(line.Trim());
                    numbersCounter++;
                }
                addItemToListBox(listbxMessages, ofdPhones.FileName + " loaded.");
                addItemToListBox(listbxMessages, numbersCounter + " records found in the file.");

            }
        }

        // add item to the listbox and move scroll to the end of the listbox for the latest messages to be visibile to the viewer
        private void addItemToListBox(ListBox listbox, String item)
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(item);
            listbox.SelectedIndex = (listbox.Items.Count - 1);
        }

        private void radioNumbers_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!radioNumbers.Checked)
            {
                grpbxNumbers.Text = "Names and Addresses";
            }
            else
            {
                grpbxNumbers.Text = "Numbers";
            }
        }

        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listbxNumbers.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records have been loaded." + "\n" + "Use the browse button to load records.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (!CheckForInternetConnection())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No internet connection.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                String response;
                switch (comboSelectSearchEngine.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0: // Hitta.se
                        foreach (String item in listbxNumbers.Items)
                        {
                            WebRequestObj request = new WebRequestObj(item, "hitta");
                            response = request.sendRequest();
                            if (response.Equals("Error"))
                            {
                                addItemToListBox(listbxMessages, "Error sending '" + item + "' to the server.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //create a temporary file to work on the response
                                StreamWriter sw;
                                if (!File.Exists(path)) {
                                    sw = File.CreateText(path);
                                }
                                try
                                {
                                    File.WriteAllText(path, String.Empty); // clear the content of the file
                                    sw = File.AppendText(path);
                                    sw.WriteLine(response);
                                    sw.Flush();
                                    sw.Close();
                                    String s = findResultType(path);
                                    MessageBox.Show(s);
                                }
                                catch (IOException ioe)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(ioe.Message,"Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                }


                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool CheckForInternetConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /*
         * findResultType
         * gets the web response and finds out if the matching result of the search termis one of the following:
         * 1. one person (oneperson)
         * 2. one company (onecompany)
         * 3. more than one person, no company (manypersonnocompany)
         * 4. no person, more than one company (nopersonmanycompany)
         * 5. more than one person, more than one company (manypersonmanycompany)
         * 6. no person, no company (nopersonnocompany)
         */
        public String findResultType(String reponsepath)
        {                   
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reponsepath);
            List<String> itemList = new List<String>();
            IEnumerable<String> v = null;
            var item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@id='person']");

            if (item != null)
            {
                v = item.Select(p => p.InnerText);
                itemList = v.ToList();
                if (itemList.Count == 1)
                    return "oneperson";
            }
            else
            {
                item = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body[@id='company']");
                if (item != null)
                {
                    v = item.Select(p => p.InnerText);
                    itemList = v.ToList();
                    if (itemList.Count == 1)
                        return "onecompany";
                }
            }

            //for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(itemList[i]);
            //    //console.writeline(itemlist[i]);
            //}
            //console.writeline(itemlist.count + " results found.");
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could remove irrelevant code, e.g. the `using` lines and implementations of methods, and highlight on which line the build error is.

Comment: and every time I do that people say you need to put your complete code here.

Comment: @Pedram Then you need to put more effort into determining what is relevant and what is not. Unfortunately, that is something that takes practice. But could you please show us where the compiler error occurred?

Comment: @Pedram: You should include complete code, but it doesn't need to be all of your original code. You should cut down your original code until you have a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem but has no code which is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is your first problem:

```
public static class frmMain : Form
```

You can't derive a static class from another class. A static class always implicitly derives from `Object`. You also can't have non-static members in static classes.

So basically, you can't put your extension method in your `frmMain` class (which should be renamed to follow .NET naming conventions and to be somewhat more descriptive at the same time). Why did you *want* to put the extension method in that class anyway?

I can't even see an extension method in the code you've posted - did you remove it? Is it in some other class you *haven't* posted?

Fundamentally, I think you need to take a step back. It sounds like you've reacted to the compiler error message without really understanding it fully. Read up on extension methods, read up on what static classes are, until you really *understand* why you don't want your form class to be static, and why you *do* want to make the class that contains your extension method static.

Comment: +1 for "It sounds like you've reacted to the compiler error message without really understanding it fully."

Comment: No, I saw it on another post that I have to add "static" before my class. I have removed it now and I do not have an extension method in my code. But the error is still there.

Comment: @Pedram You need to create a *new* class, as per my answer.

Comment: @Kendall Frey create a new class for what? I don't have extension methods in my code. Do I? And I don't want them.

Comment: @Pedram: Did you read my answer and understand it? It's *not* as simple as just adding `static` before a class declaration - that will only work if the class is *valid* as a static class, which yours certainly isn't. And if you don't have any extension methods, you shouldn't have got an error message about them to start with...

Comment: @Pedram: When you got the error message in the title, the compiler should have shown you which line had the problem. Please tell us which class is involved, and which line of code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes and that's why I am confused. No extension methods.

Comment: @Pedram: I'm afraid I simply don't believe you. Again, the compiler *will* have given you a source file and a line number. You haven't given us that information.

Comment: the line is: public class frmMain : Form

Comment: @Pedram: That line certainly wouldn't have given the error about extension methods. It *would* have given an error about you trying to create a static class which derives from another.

Comment: but I'm not creating a static class. I don't have a static class in my code.

Comment: @Pedram Yes you do. `public static class frmMain : Form` That's a static class. (And it throws an error)

Comment: Yes that was the initial problem. But I have changed that line in my code half an hour ago.

Comment: it is now public class frmMain : Form

Comment: @Pedram: ... and if you've removed the static modifer, I'm pretty sure you'll find the error location will have moved, too...

Comment: now the error text has changed to: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'PhoneFind.frmMain'; another partial declaration of this type exists.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just tested, and the error does in fact occur at the class declaration.

Comment: @Pedram: Yes, I bet you removed the `partial` modifier when you added the `static` modifier... You need to get back to the state where you had the error message about extension methods.

Comment: @Pedram You need to add `partial` to the class definition, since the other half of the class is defined in another file. Also, there is an extension method somewhere in your code. Please find it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I get the error on the class declaration line, not the method declaration. I don't want to start an argument, but I saw it with my own eyes.

Comment: I found that my Form1.designer.cs is also called frmMain and it's partial. Does it help to suggest a solution?

Comment: @Pedram Probably not, since there shouldn't be any extension methods in there, because it's auto-generated.

Comment: @KendallFrey: *Which* error though? The one in the title, or one saying "Static class frmMain cannot derive..." (See my comment at 16:28:25Z.)

Comment: if there's any renaming solution to this please let me know. my designer class has no extension methods either.

Comment: @Pedram: Yes, both Kendall and I have said, you need to put back the `partial` modifier which you removed when you added the `static` modifier. Then maybe we can get to the situation where you *actually* get the error message you've given in the question, which there's been no evidence for thus far.

Comment: @JonSkeet The one in the title. The one with a blue squiggly. Are you looking at the one with red squiggly?

Comment: I'm sure this is driving you mad too. The error does not change it's still "missing partial modifier". I have changed both of them to partial. Yes I know the designer class is auto-generated.

Comment: @KendallFrey: I don't have Visual Studio open, so I have no squigglies at all, but having copied and pasted the exact code posted into a text file and tried to compile, there's no sign of the error in the question title. Please could you mail me (skeet@pobox.com) a complete solution which gives you the extension method error?

Comment: If it's just a pop-up, perhaps try clicking on Build -> Rebuild Solution.

Comment: OMG! Rebuilt Solution solved my problem! Thank you so very much @ispiro that was the most stupid error ever.

Comment: No. Not stupid. We tend to assume that Visual Studio does everything exact. It doesn't. :)

Answer (score 1):

A `static` class cannot have public constructors. Moreover, `static` forms are pointless, as you need an instance of them to show.

If you have an extension method (I don't see any...), you have to move it into a separate `static` class which you cannot create instances of:

```
static class MyExtensions
{
  public static void Extend(this Object o) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always put your extension methods in a separate static class.

You can't fix the problem by simply marking a class as static. That changes the entire meaning of the class. Instead, create a new class for just extension methods.

For example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public void SomeExtension(this object arg)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have extension methods. I don't want them. I just don't know why my code is generating this error.

Comment: @Pedram Maybe the extension method is in another class. Go to the line the error mentions to find the problem.

Comment: @Pedram: You *do* have an extension method, just not in the code you've shown. The compiler will show you where. I've *never* seen the C# compiler "make up" an error to do with an extension method.